# How to prevent Simperium for authorizing automatically?

Tags: ios, simperium

I want to allow my new users to play with the app a bit before I prompt them to create a Simperium account.  How can I control authorization?

I used to be able to call:

`self.simperium.authenticationEnabled = NO;`

until I wanted Simperium to prompt the user to sign in, at which point I'd call:

`simperium.authenticationEnabled = YES;
[simperium authenticateIfNecessary];`

Alas, `authenticationEnabled` doesn't seem to be available anymore.  I'm currently using the `develop` branch.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the new api, you can simply do as follows:

1. Initialize Simperium (which, in turn, wires your Core Data stack):

   self.simperium = [[Simperium alloc] initWithModel:self.managedObjectModel
                   context:self.managedObjectContext
                   coordinator:self.persistentStoreCoordinator];
2. Once you're ready to enable sync'ing (and thus, authenticate the user):

   [_simperium authenticateWithAppID:@"{SIMPERIUM_APP_ID}"
                   APIKey:@"{SIMPERIUM_APP_KEY}"
                   rootViewController:_window.rootViewController];

(No need to flip the authenticationEnabled flag anymore!)
Hope that helps!

Comment: Ok, I tried this, and it does work, thank you.  However, there's a small hiccup with the new API.  The SPAuthenticator.needsAuthentication function doesn't work like it used to before authorization because the appID hasn't been set yet... So I had to copy that function and pass in my appID.  It's a hack, but it works.  I'd love to hear if you have a better solution.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!. I see the use case (i.e. display a different message label if the 'toggle sync' button will end up presenting a new viewController).

I've just added a new issue to update the needsAuthentication helper. Thanks again!!

(Ref: https://github.com/Simperium/simperium-ios/issues/434)

Comment: Thanks for filing the ticket.  I should have explained my use case.  Upon start up, if my user already has an account, I want to sign in automatically (behind the scenes).  But if they don't have an account, I don't want to prompt them to create one right away.  I want to let them use the app a few times, then prompt them.